# Total the values for variables for variable categories in another frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames - the first being simple numeric observations / values for some variables:

```
var1 <- c(1,0,0,1)
var2 <- c(1,1,2,0)
var3 <- c(1,2,0,1)
var4 <- c(2,1,0,1)
var5 <- c(1,2,0,1)
var6 <- c(1,1,1,1)
df <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6)
```

The second data frame gives categories for the variables:

```
var_names <- c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6")
sub_type <- c("red", "blue", "red", "green", "green", "blue")
var_types <- data.frame(var_names, sub_type)
```

I'd like to be able to add the values together for each category and place into a new data frame. So from this example I'd have a new data frame of 4 rows / observations for the 3 variables of red, blue & green.  Seems simple, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading your question, it seems that you want to do the following. You said "a new data frame of 4 rows / observations for the 3 variables of red, blue & green". So I think you want to have a data frame with four rows and three columns (three colors). First, I added row number to `df` and converted the data in long format. In the column, `color`, I had variable names such as `var1`, `var2`, and `var3`. I wanted to change them to colors. I have done that in `mutate()` using `match()`. Then, grouping the data by row number and color, I summed up value. Finally, I converted the data frame into wide format. If necessary, you want to remove `rowname` in the output.

```
library(tidyverse)

rownames_to_column(df) %>%
gather(key = color, value = value, -rowname) %>%
mutate(color = var_types$sub_type[match(color, var_types$var_names)]) %>%
group_by(rowname, color) %>%
summarize(total = sum(value)) %>%
spread(key = color, value = total)

  rowname  blue green   red
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1        2.00  3.00  2.00
2 2        2.00  3.00  2.00
3 3        3.00  0     0   
4 4        1.00  2.00  2.00
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you could do the following as well. You take columns for each color and use `rowSums()`. Then, you create a data frame and assign columns names to it.

```
colors <- unique(var_types$sub_type)

colors %>%
map(function(x) rowSums(df[, which(var_types$sub_type == x)])) %>%
as.data.frame %>%
setNames(colors)

  red blue green
1   2    2     3
2   2    2     3
3   0    3     0
4   2    1     2
```

Comment: Pleasure to help you. :)

Comment: @nycrefugee I just added another option as a reference. This is probably simpler.

Comment: I'm going to stick with your original solution for now, but will test your alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyr` and `dplyr`. Modified answer thanks to jazzurro:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  gather(key = "var_names", value = "value", -id) %>% 
  left_join(var_types) %>% 
  group_by(sub_type, id) %>% 
  summarize(total = sum(value)) %>%
  spread(sub_type, total)
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
     id  blue green   red
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  2.00  3.00  2.00
2     2  2.00  3.00  2.00
3     3  3.00  0     0   
4     4  1.00  2.00  2.00
```

The data I used. Note that I changed `var_types` `df` to treat strings as `character` not `factor`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  var1 = c(1,0,0,1),
  var2 = c(1,1,2,0),
  var3 = c(1,2,0,1),
  var4 = c(2,1,0,1),
  var5 = c(1,2,0,1),
  var6 = c(1,1,1,1)
)

var_types <- data.frame(
  var_names = c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6"),
  sub_type = c("red", "blue", "red", "green", "green", "blue"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```